# How to empty items from owlCarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have an model where is I am showing some couple of images are showing in owlCarousel div. But problem is that when I close that model and again open it again. then the images are append to previous images. So I want to do something happen to clear all items from previous model and reinit that owlCarousel.
I have tried :

```
var $carousel = $(".edit-manage-carousel");
for (var i =0; i<100; i++) {
  $carousel.trigger('remove.owl.carousel', i );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing wrong.

Here is correct way to do so.

```
for (var i=0; i<$('.item').length; i++) {
   $(".edit-manage-carousel").trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [i])
                             .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Manish Prajapati response is correct, but the number of the items should be saved in a variable and not calculated at each iteration. 
The reason is, whether there are more than one element the number of items changes at each iteration leaving the last one in.

I think that this one should work better, let me know if I am in error:

```
var length = $('.item').length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
   $(".edit-manage-carousel").trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [i])
                             .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
}
```